# C# Auto Cpu Usage refresh

Tags: c#

I have this code :

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
        cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
        cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
        cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";
        PerformanceCounter ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
        var unused = cpuCounter.NextValue(); // first call will always return 0
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

        label1.Text = "Cpu usage: :" + cpuCounter.NextValue() + "%";
        label2.Text = "Free ram : " + ramCounter.NextValue() + "MB";
    }
```

What to write to the program will automatically change% CPU utilization, not by pressing a button ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simulate `ButtonClick` event for specific `interval` you can use `Timer` Control.

**Step 1:** You need to Subscribe to the `Timer Tick` event.
**Step 2:** Set the `Interval` property of the `Timer` to 1000 milliseconds for raising the event for every 1 Second.
**Step 3:** In `Tick Event Handler`  just call the `Button Click` Event Handler.
**Step 4:** you can Call the  `timer1.Stop()` method whenever you want to stop the timer.

Try This:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer1.Interval=1000;//one second
timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
timer1.Start();

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Call the Button1 Click Event Handler
     button1_Click(sender,e);

     //Stop Timer whenever you want.
     //timer1.Stop(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) to make the task reoccurring. Also to solve the "first call will always return 0" issue just re-use the same performance counter each call of the timer.

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
    cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
    cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
    cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";
    ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");


    //It is better to add the timer via the Design View so it gets disposed properly when the form closes.
    //timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    //This setup can be done in the design view too, you just need to call timer.Start() at the end of your constructor (On form load would be even better however, ensures all of the controls have their handles created).
    timer.Interval=1000;
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

//private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer; //Added via Design View

private PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
private PerformanceCounter ramCounter;


private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Cpu usage: :" + cpuCounter.NextValue() + "%";
    label2.Text = "Free ram : " + ramCounter.NextValue() + "MB";
}
```